# docker image run failing, ipmi_exporter for Prometheus

Tags: docker, prometheus

I'm trying to create a docker image of soundcloud/ipmi-exporter to run with Prometheus on Ubuntu Bionic with Docker 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c. Docker on my OS X laptop is Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61. I am forced to build the (customized) image on my laptop because Bionic has a version of golang that's older than what ipmi-exporter wants, and I'm not allowed to update the Ubuntu server.

Anyway, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my Dockerfile?

```sh
# Container image
FROM quay.io/prometheus/golang-builder:1.13-base AS builder
ADD . /go/src/github.com/soundcloud/ipmi_exporter/
RUN cd /go/src/github.com/soundcloud/ipmi_exporter && make

# Container image
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install freeipmi-tools -y --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/soundcloud/ipmi_exporter/ipmi_exporter /bin/ipmi_exporter

EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["ipmi_exporter"]
CMD ["--config.file", "/ipmi_remote.yml"]
CMD ["--web.listen-address=":8889"" "--freeipmi.path=/etc/freeipmi" "--log.level="debug""]
```

When I run the image all I see is

```
ipmi_exporter: error: unexpected /bin/sh, try --help
```

I have ipmi_exporter running on the OS directly and I never configured a config.yml. What config.yml is the Dockerfile author talking about? It's mentioned in the last line of https://github.com/soundcloud/ipmi_exporter/blob/master/Dockerfile

The image lives here: https://github.com/soundcloud/ipmi_exporter The sample/example Dockerfile refers to a config.yaml which this software does not use.

I just can't figure out how to make the image pull in the config file I specify.

Comment: You have two `CMD`s; the first one is ignored.  The second isn't a valid JSON array, so Docker wraps it in `sh -c '["--web.listen-address...""]'`.  Then that gets passed as extra arguments to the single `ENTRYPOINT`.  It might be easier to just write a single `CMD ipmi_exporter --web.listen-address=:8889 ...` (without `ENTRYPOINT` and without the JSON-array syntax).

Comment: The distributed Dockerfile contains the line, CMD ["--config.file", "/config.yml"]  but there's no config.yml distributed with this image. Also, when I use CMD ["--config.file", "/ipmi_remote.yml"] the resultant image can't find the file which absolutely does exist in the build directory. I don't understand docker pathnames at all.

Comment: Did you mean literally 
  CMD ipmi_exporter --web.listen-address=:8889 
without the brackets?

Comment: Yes, when you `docker run` the image it will be interpreted as an ordinary command line.

Comment: What I meant was, should I always enclose for instance "--config.file", "/ipmi_remote.yml" inside of square brackets?

Comment: If you do, it must be a valid JSON array, or Docker will fall back to treating it as a shell command.  In the form in the question there are double double quotes and missing commas between array entries.  Also if you have both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` then the `ENTRYPOINT` must be the JSON-array form.  The [Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) has more detail; the syntax there also applies to `CMD` and `RUN`.